# auto type deduction of function return value

Tags: c++, c++14, auto, type-deduction

I am watching Scott Meyers's online video and have a different result with his presentation. Here is the code:

```
auto LookupValue(int i) {
    static vector<int> values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    return values[i];
}
```

I got a waring for the return line with the information: 'Returning 'int&' from a function returning 'void''. 
Why the returning value deduce to void?

Here is my testbed:

```
fetag@MacgicBox ~$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

just a quick update:
I test the return value as follows, and the compile DO set the return type with integral and should be returned by value, because of only the last line output with 1, the others are all 0.

```
cout << is_lvalue_reference<decltype(LookupValue(2))>::value << endl;
cout << is_rvalue_reference<decltype(LookupValue(2))>::value << endl;
cout << is_reference<decltype(LookupValue(2))>::value << endl;
cout << is_pointer<decltype(LookupValue(2))>::value << endl;
cout << is_void<decltype(LookupValue(2))>::value << endl;
cout << is_integral<decltype(LookupValue(2))>::value << endl;
```

Update conclusion:
Finally, this is a bug of the parse component of CLion, and they promise to fix it in the next release. Here is the bug report and feedback:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-9906

Comment: Do you compile in C++11 or C++14 ?

Comment: C++ 14. C++ 11 does not support return type of functions to be auto.

Comment: That's why I asked, it might have simply been a strange error message due to the fact that with C++11 you have to use postfix return type with auto.

Comment: with ``clang++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp`` (clang 3.8) and ``g++  -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp`` (gcc 7.1) I have no warnings/errors.

Comment: How about trying to compile it with GCC or another compiler?

Comment: the same behavior with g++ 6.3.0
root@bad ~# g++ --version
g++ (Debian 6.3.0-18) 6.3.0 20170516

Comment: Works fine with `GCC 7.1.0`

Comment: Works fine here with `GCC 6.3.1`

Comment: Works fine here with `clang++ v3.9.1`

Answer (score 3):

> Why the returning value deduce to void?

The compiler made a mistake. It should deduce int, not void.

... Or the example isn't complete.